# How to change the default layout animation curve in a custom UICollectionView layout engine?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I've got a collection view setup to run with a custom collection view layout. I can animate cells appearing and disappearing by changing their transformations and alpha on the UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes, however, I would like to change the animation curve to use springs + damping in order to make the cells "bounce" when they appear.

Does anybody have an idea of how I can achieve this?

Thanks,

Comment: What code are you using at the moment?

Comment: you can do this by using `UIKitDynamics` There is a very good blog post about it. https://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/ios7-day-by-day-day-0-uikit-dynamics https://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/ios7-day-by-day-day-5-uidynamics-with-collection-views you want to download the code used in blog here is the repository
https://github.com/shinobicontrols/iOS7-day-by-day

Comment: I'm using a custom UICollectionViewLayout subclass that overrides the method: `initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndexPath`

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your UICollectionView's `deleteItems/insertItems/reloadItems` calls inside `UIView.animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:` call.

Example:

```
let duration = 0.25 // Hardcoded keyboard animation duration and curve
let curve = UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: 7 << 16) // ↑
UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0, options: curve, animations: ({ [weak self] in
    self?.collectionView?.performBatchUpdates({
        self?.collectionView?.deleteItems(at: deletedIPs)
        self?.collectionView?.insertItems(at: insertedIPs)
        self?.collectionView?.reloadItems(at: updatedIPs)
    }, completion: nil)
}), completion: nil)
```